# NotificationCompat .AddAction not supports String parameter

Tags: android, notifications

I'm trying to create a Notification.

This is my sample code:

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setContentTitle("My notification")
            .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_camera, getResources().getString(R.string.Action), NotificationReceiverActivity.class)
            .setContentText("Hello World!");
```

But Eclipse is telling me, that the method `addAction` is not applicable for this arguments:

> The method addAction(int, CharSequence, PendingIntent) in the type NotificationCompat.Builder is not applicable for the arguments (int, String, Class)

What's the problem?

This minSdkVersion is 16 and the targetSdkVersion is 17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third parameter to `addAction()` needs to be a `PendingIntent`, but you are passing a class. Do something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiverActivity.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
        .setContentTitle("My notification")
        .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_camera, getResources().getString(R.string.Action), pi)
        .setContentText("Hello World!");
```

Look at other examples of using the notification builder and/or using `PendingIntent` if you need more help.